# Validate AngularJS collection has items

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

I've got a form where multiple rows can be added to a particular collection. I'm displaying the inputs with a `ng-repeat`.

I want to add validation that there is at least one item in the collection, and prevent submission if there isn't.

Since the validation isn't on an input value, but instead on a property of the controller I can't seem to work out:

1. Where to put the validation
2. How to get the validation to run when the collection length changes

Comment: Does the `ng-submit` directive help at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ngDisabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) directive on the submit button to achieve it:

```
<div ng-show="dataList.length == 0">Add at least one record</div>
......
<button ng-disabled="dataList.length == 0">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Yes but there are other fields, and also it wouldn't be particularly obvious as to why the button is disabled, I'd prefer to show a message like "Add at least one record" so the user knows why it's disabled. Which I guess I could do with a `ngShow` and the same expression, but it'd also not be testable

Comment: @slace You can use e2e tests to test the template data binding. The correctness of template logic such as binding and expression evaluation should be considered as the correctness of the framework.  And you have to assume the framework is flawless. Or the testability can't be achieved since you already assume the framework could go wrong.